# How to insert image on Tiff file without changing the DPI of tiff file?

Tags: c#

I want to do stamping on tiff file (Png image on tiff) but without changing its properties like DPI.
 I have tried below code but it is reducing the size of tiff.

```cs
System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = (System.Drawing.Bitmap) System.Drawing.Image.FromFile (inputpath);

Bitmap EditableImg = new Bitmap (bitmap);
System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmapStamping = (System.Drawing.Bitmap) System.Drawing.Image.FromFile (stamppath);
using (System.Drawing.Graphics graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage (EditableImg)) {
    graphics.DrawImage (bitmapStamping, secondLocation);

}

EditableImg.Save (outputpath);
```

Comment: The Save method will default to PNG, might be as easy as 
EditableImg.Save (outputpath, ImageFormat.Tiff);

Comment: `new Bitmap (bitmap);` this defaults the dpi to the __current screen__ dpi. You should then set it to the original values of the tiff image : `((Bitmap)img).SetResolution(oImg.HorizontalResolution, oImg.VerticalResolution);` The same btw goes for the stamp image..

Comment: Changing the compression of file to LZW where as my original files compression is CCITT T.6 and reducing the DPI.     EditableImg.Save (outputpath, ImageFormat.Tiff); this did not help. @fuchs777